# How to check Game Build Errors?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build, game-development

I am currently developing an RPG game on Unity 2017.1. When I run it in the editor, everything runs smoothly, but when I build the game, the animation on my main character does not run. When I check the output log, I get this message

> Internal: JobTempAlloc has allocations that are more than 4 frames old - this is not allowed and likely a leak
>   (Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Allocator/ThreadsafeLinearAllocator.cpp Line: 371)

link to the output log is in the comment section.

Is that why my animation isn't running? if not, is there a way to check my animation in the game build?

Comment: Please next time provide the error as a text.

Comment: that message can come up, not entirely sure why but animations usually stil work - posting the error as a picture is less nice as in time to come people cant search on it and the link maybe become invalid.  But being said, there is a lot more in that file.. chances are there are other errors that are more important

Comment: Btw that a sign of a memory leaking as the log says, you either did not free a Native container/job or using a reference type inside a job etc. However this is not an error so i don't think so that's why your animation aint playing, you should provide the code what's play your animation or give more context

Comment: i'm sorry. I changed it

Comment: Your ink to output.log seems invalid

Comment: Do you guys have any idea how to check why my animation isn't working?

Comment: Output Log : https://pastebin.com/5tTWJrGs